# How can I set a global variable in Razor Pages of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanna to check if the browser is IE and do something in razor page.

I just made a function in razor page to do that.

However, I think use the function to check if the browser is IE in every razor page is redundant. For independent user, I just need to check this only one time and set a global variable that `IsIE=true/false` . And other page will easily know that if it is IE.

The question is how can I get/set a global variable in razor page?

Thank you.

————————————————
To @Neville Nazerane ,here is the function which to check if is IE:

```
@{
    Boolean IsIE = false;
    string UA = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
    if (UA.Contains("Trident") || UA.Contains("MSIE"))
    {
        IsIE = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsIE = false; ;
    }    
    if (IsIE == true)
    {
       
    }
    else
    {
       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you want to use "global" variable which reusable in other views? I think you should look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789887/how-to-make-a-variable-in-the-razor-view-global.

Comment: can you show the function you have made? mainly the parameters and properties you are using within the page

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I showed just now,please have a look,thank you.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I think is almost the same.However,it seems no one gives a best answer.Someone said using sesstion,and someone said session will occur new problem.

Comment: i don't think u'll need to set a global variable. it seems like you need to store something different for each user's each browser. that will be more like a cookie or session if that's what you want

Comment: This reeks of an XY problem. Why do you even need to know if it's IE in the first place? Without client-side feature detection, there's no way to know for sure. The user agent string can be *easily* manipulated.

Comment: @ChrisPratt client side can be manipulated as well. no harm in getting the user agent from the request in the server side. the overall concept can't be used for any kind of security. that's all

Comment: My point is that is simply generally the wrong approach to begin with. Most normally it's to try to lock something down to IE only, and a lot of users intentionally send an IE user agent simply because of things like this, even if they're running Firefox or Chrome. Feature detection is not fakeable. Either the browser supports it or it doesn't. Now, a user could try to weave in their own JS to try to override what you're doing, but that's a bit more difficult.

Comment: The bottom line is that in both cases it is possible to fake. Which makes it unsafe to do the check for this reason overall. So, if this security was the OPs intention, either ways isn't recommended. These checks are also done often for displaying different data to different browsers. In this case, both approaches should be fine.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes,you are right,maybe I do not explain clearly.I need to store something different for each use's each browser.

Comment: Oh,althought user agent can be easily manipulated,however I just use it to decide which css to use only.haha@ChrisPratt

Comment: I just use it to decide which css to use only.I don't care hacker manipulate the user agent.@NevilleNazerane

Comment: yeah this css is one of the most common usages. that's what i though. Check my answer though to get a better answer on each user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP requests work by clients sending a request (with header and body) to your server. Your server can then access this info and send a response. This doesn't create any persistent (ongoing) connection between the server and client. This means there is no permanent link between your server and each client. Any global variable you declare will be global for your server's web application and will be common for every client.

What you are trying to do here is create variables isolated from each client's connection. Normally this is done with the help of `Session` or `Cookie` variable. But in this case, I don't see how this will improve any performance over the code you have written. In your code, you are trying to access the Http Headers from the request. Cookies and session variables are also accessed in a very similar way. If anything fetching directly from headers must have a slightly better performance. If you are trying to clean up your code so you don't have to write this on every page, services could be quite helpful.

You can create a class for service something like this:

```
public class AgentChecker
{

    public bool IsIE { get; set; }

    // makes sure check is done only when object is created
    public AgentChecker(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        string UA = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        if (UA.Contains("Trident") || UA.Contains("MSIE"))
        {
            IsIE = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsIE = false; 
        }
    }

    // optional to simplify usage further. 
    public static implicit operator bool(AgentChecker checker) => checker.IsIE;

}
```

In your startup class add the following:

```
// to access http context in a service
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
// makes sure object is created once per request
services.AddScoped<AgentChecker>();
```

Once this is set up, in your view you can use:

```
@inject AgentChecker checker

@* if you didn't create the implicit operator, you can use if (checker.IsIE) *@
@if (checker)
{
    <div>Is ie</div>
}
else
{
    <div>not ie</div>
}
```

The `inject` goes at the top of any view page you would like to use this in. While this still creates a new object each request, it is cleaner to use and only creates one object no matter how many partial views you are using.

Comment: I think it is the correct answer,but I wonder why do not use cookies?

Comment: You can use cookies. But in this case, you will not get any advantage. Cookies are also passed with your HTTP header and your server needs to go through the same process. If anything that will be more work for your server and for you

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `HttpContextAccessor`. You can directly reference `this.Request.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]` once you add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides` nuget package.