# Create Global variable in .NET Core 2.0 to use in razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a button that appears on several pages in my application. (Pages that are called from varying controllers.)

```
<a ... class="btn btn-primary">Complete New Survey</a>
```

The text within the button "Complete New Survey" I would liek to set as a global variable somewhere. As if the customer wants this to be "Start new survey", I don't want to have to do find and replace throughout the whole application.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
<a ... class="btn btn-primary">@GlobalVars["NewSurveyButton"]</a>
```

And define it somewhere in a file like:

```
GlobalVars["NewSurveyButton"] = "Start new survey"
```

Comment: You can use static variables to achieve this , although I don't like static variables inside web, What i recommend is using shared localization file or create a base view model and put the shared data across pages inside it.

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani thanks, although I think that might be overkill - it means adding a view model to all these pages just for one variable? Also.. any idea why my question is being downvoted?

Comment: Well, I always create view model for each page I added so It is based on your structure of the website, then I should you can add a static variable to your startup class and use it inside your razor

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani OK, but I'm still not sure how to call the static variable in startup from my view? Also, is it possible to make use of appsettings.json? Or _ViewStart.cshtml?

Comment: You can refer to this question I have asked:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624242/how-can-i-set-a-global-variable-in-razor-page-of-net-core

Comment: See my answer for an example about using static variables

Comment: This is pretty much the *exact* use case for a resource file. It's primarily for localization, but it serves that purpose because it abstracts away the text on things like buttons into a single location. Use a resource file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use static variable (or const variable) inside your startup class as following:

First of all define the string variable that you want to put the button label value inside:

```
public static string SharedButtonLabel = "My button shared label";
```

Then inside your razor code you can write the following:

```
<button>@MyProject.Startup.SharedButtonLabel</button>
```

Where "MyProject" is the namespace of your project

Answer (score 4):

Working with ASP.Net Core 2.1 here.

You can use the *ViewStart.cshtml* file to set a value from the server and add it to the ViewData.

In your example, here is how the *ViewStart.cshtml* file will look like.

```
@ {
  Layout = "_Layout";
  ViewData["NewSurveyButton"] = "Start new survey"; // Add it here
}
```

Then, you can simply access the ViewData in any other Razor View. Consider *Home/Index.cshtml* for example.

```
<div>
    <button>@ViewData["NewSurveyButton"]</button>
</div>
```

The same ViewData key can be accessed similarly in all other Razor Views, which makes ViewData["NewSurveyButton"] act like a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Localization with a SharedResource object. Such a solution is for example: https://github.com/MrSteinster/ASP.NET-Core-Localization

Comment: Sorry if this is dumb but I can't figure out how to run the sample - I've cloned it with VS2017 but no files show in the solution explorer. Presumably as it does not come with a solution or project file...

Comment: I recently used this project as a guideline for myself. The only thing you have to do is actually place an empty class in a folder (for example in views/shared/SharedResources.cs) and then create a resource file under Resources/views/shared/SharedResources.resx) and fill it with your values. You can see how to access those values in the example project in the /views/shared/_Layout.cshtml view. That's all

Comment: OK, I thought I had it then, but when I put `@sharedLocalizer["Test"]` in my view, the rendered text is just "Test". That's the Name. I want the Value ("Hello"). I realised whatever I change "Test" to, it will just display that text.

Comment: If you just see the "Key" then the resource file is not found or the key is not present in the resource file. You should doublecheck your spelling, I guess the Key is case sensitive, and double check the location of your SharedResources.cs and SharedResources.resx file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseController if you don´t have one and use `OnActionExecuting`:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            ViewBag.Text = "Start new survey";
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }  
    }
```

`BaseController` extends from `Controller`. All your other controllers must now extend form `BaseController` so that on your views you have access to this `ViewBag`.

```
@ViewBag.Text
```

Comment: Base controllers are a *hugely* bad idea in general, and especially for something like this.

Comment: Is it that bad? I'm new to ASP.Net and i use them to solve some things. Do you have any simple explanation why thy are so bad? Not trying to be rude, I just want to learn good practices.@ChrisPratt

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, but I'd say 99% of the time, a base controller is the wrong way to go. There's tons of other options that work better for most scenarios: action filters, view components, etc. Particularly for something like this, it's very dangerous because you now have a view dependency on a controller inheriting from a specific base class. If you forget to do that or can't do that (remember that C# supports only single inheritance), then your view blows up.

Comment: Single inheritance is a particularly big issue here as well. If you could do mixins like with a language like Python, that would be one thing, but because you can only inherit from one base controller, you'll end up violating just about every part of SOLID with this approach.

Comment: So, in my case, for example, I have a `User` class that extends from `IdentityUser`. This `User` class has some custom attributes, and I use Base controller to get the current logged in user, do some logic, so that I can send 1 custom attribute to the view through the `ViewBag`.  What do you recommend doing? At the time I couldn't get an answer to this, that was my way of working it out. I'm not asking for the answer, just point me to the right direction. @ChrisPratt

Comment: Action filter would be the best way.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the attribute in question is the user's name. So i need it in all of my views, in like a partial view throughout my entire app. @ChrisPratt

Comment: Well, given the partial view portion, a view component may be a better approach. That way, it's completely secluded from everything else going on in the app. However, you can add a global action filter just as well.